# Trajectory of a particle in a string or a rope that goes under the effect of a wave pulse

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, continuum-mechanics, string

What is the trajectory of a particle in a string or a rope that goes under the effect of a wave pulse.

[image]

The illustration in this image is not what I am asking about, I just attached it in order to give you an idea of the case I mean.

If you give me a picture of the trajectory, I'd be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the particle attached to the string, or is it allowed to slide along the string?

Comment: No, it's attached to the string, precisely it's a part of the string.

Comment: Hi صهيب أبو ريدة. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Please provide more explanation. It is not clear what you are asking about. The image mentions the trajectory of particles *in 2 different reference frames* - relative to the pulse, and relative to the ground.

Comment: Sammy gerbil, I want it relative to the ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the particle is in and attached to the string,they would undergo time-dependent,periodic vertical displacement and oscillation.

Imagine you put a ball in the string and record it's shadow while the wave propogates.